# Mark multiple options as selected, database results

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `post_languages` (columns: `languageID`, `languageName`) and `post_to_languages` (`languageID`, `postID`) and a select form.

I want to mark one or multiple option tags as selected by languageID using the results from the database. Don't want only to display the languages, I want to mark them as selected from a list of languages provided by the table post_languages.

What I have tried, but only one language is selected, `$res` returns only one ID:

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT languageID FROM post_to_languages WHERE postID = :postID');
$stmt->execute(array(':postID'=>$postID));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt2 = $db->prepare('SELECT languageID, languageName FROM post_languages ORDER BY languageName');
$stmt2->execute();
echo '<select class="post-language form-control" name="postLangID[]" multiple="multiple" required>';
while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        if ($row2['languageID'] == $res) {
            $selected = 'selected';
        } else {
            $selected = '';
        }                      
    } 
    echo '<option value="'.$row2['languageID'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$row2['languageName'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Can you show example value for `$postID` ?

Comment: var_dump for $postID: string(2) "41"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reason is `$stmt` query. You have filtration by `postID` field.
The second one is type of `$res` variable i think it's an `array`. Please try to `var_dump` it.
I think it could look sth like:

```
foreach ($result as $res) {
        if ($row2['languageID'] == $res['languageID']) {
            $selected = 'selected';
        } else {
        $selected = '';
    }                      
}
```

If `$postID` is an `Array` you can also try this code:

```
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($postID), '?'));
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT languageID, languageName, IF(post_languages.languageID IN (SELECT post_to_languages.languageID FROM post_to_languages WHERE post_to_languages.postID IN ($place_holders)), 1, 0) as selected FROM post_languages ORDER BY languageName");
$stmt->execute($postID);
echo '<select class="post-language form-control" name="postLangID[]" multiple="multiple" required>';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($row["selected"]) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['languageID'].'" selected>'.$row['languageName'].'</option>';
    } else {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['languageID'].'">'.$row['languageName'].'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: var_dump for $postID: string(2) "41", var_dump for $res: string(1) "5"

Comment: So, you fetch only one row from `post_to_languages` table because you have filtration by `postID` field in `WHERE clause`. Remove it or parse it as array with more values to get selected langs.

Comment: I have used  
$langs = array();
  while(($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
         $langs[] = $result;
     }
     
to retun both languages from the database, but var_dump on $langs returns this: 

array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["languageID"]=> string(1) "5" } [1]=> array(1) { ["languageID"]=> string(3) "106" } }

and from here don't know how to exactly get only the IDs, if I use foreach, i get only one array.

Comment: @flav.rsu Store posts ids in array `$postId` and use second from my answer. for example `$postId = [1,2,3,4];`